# Is there a reason a TA and a professor may have to travel together?

Tags: conference, professorship, teaching-assistant

I don't work in academia but I'm working on a screenplay set in that world. I was wondering if there might be a reason for a TA and a professor to travel together for work. If the professor were attending an academic conference, would it be normal for the TA to go with? Thanks!

Comment: Often the TA is the professor's student, in which case they will often attend conferences together.

Comment: A teaching assistant? Not unless it's a pedagogy conference. A _research assistant_, maybe.

Comment: @aeismail The TAs of my courses are also PhD students of mine, so indeed we frequently go to conferences together.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Yes, but they're not going to the conference because they're your TA.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, everyone! Is there a reason why students attend conferences with you? In the case of my screenplay, the professor is teaching a creative writing class and the TA is her student.

Comment: Why set your screenplay in an unfamiliar environment?

Comment: The closest bond is between a student and his or her thesis advisor.  I had some great conversations with my advisor while driving him to the airport.  Does that count as travel?

Comment: @aeismail Ha, yes, of course.

Comment: @GregF: It's unlikely that you'd even have a TA in a creative writing course. The reason for attending the conference would usually be to present one's one research. You'd be better off with a discipline that does field work—then it's much more likely to have the student travel with the advisor.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Because screenplays set in a film-industry environment become boring quite quickly?

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, a teaching assistant would not have any reason to travel with their professor, since their responsibilities are around teaching. Perhaps if the class was an expedition for field work in an archaeological department or something (I think I have heard of a department doing this), but then it would have all of the students as well.

A research assistant, on the other hand, will often travel to a conference with their advisor, if they have a paper or poster to present. Thus, to me, the most likely case for a teaching assistant traveling with a professor is if they are also supervised in research by that same professor.

Comment: Many TAs are also RAs or otherwise engaged in research. These are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Thomas That is the point of my second paragraph. In the US, at least, TA and RA are typically descriptions of the means of financial support for a student.  When dealing with graduate students, all are typically engaged in research, but not necessarily with a professor that they are TAing for.  Undergraduate TAs, of course, might not be doing any research at all.

Comment: Some undergrads do do research. I once filled in for a week when both the professor and undergrad TA of a course were at a conference.

Comment: @Thomas Again, I am unsure what you are disagreeing with in my statements: "undergraduate TAs might not be doing research" also implies that many might be doing research.  The point is that it is the research relationship that typically leads to joint travel, not the teaching relationship.

Answer (score 2):

This could happen when the course is not taught at the home university. For example, a collegue of mine taught a course as part of an international exchange program focussing on mobility of teachers rather than mobility of students. He took his TAs with him. I have attended a summer school where people from across the world taught courses. Again they tended to take their TAs with them. This happens in real live, but it is definately not the rule. So I am a bit worried that this may look a bit too contrived in a screen play. As others have already mentioned, traveling with an RA would be much more likely.

Answer (score 0):

In my graduate school in engineering I was aware of an especially poorly-funded group where the professor (70-80 y.o.) and 2-4 research assistant students (all 27-35 y.o.) would drive from east coast to Cincinnati in same car for conference and ALL SHARED THE SAME HOTEL ROOM (2 beds)! quelle horreur! Although the professor liked creeping on female students all persons involved were hetero cis males so no funnie business here, just a humiliating level of frugality.